# Using terraform - how to check and edit users on AWS that already exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Our AWS account has users. We are now trying to use CI using Terraform to manage the old users and the new users. Terraform requires complete control of the service - agreed, but how can I make it work with what exists? 
Problem : I am able to add groups,roles,policies to the new users created via terraform but I am unable to add groups/policies/edit the users that were previously created on AWS account.

I am on Terraform version 12.

I have tried to use the data resource and count to check for its existence

```
#data "aws_iam_user" "upload_iam_user" {
#  user_name = "${var.service_name}"
#}

#resource "aws_iam_user" "upload_iam_user" {
#  count= "${data.aws_iam_user.upload_iam_user != "null" ? 0 : 1}"
#  name = "${var.service_name}"
#}
```

This data only checks if it exists but, it does not perform the creation if it does not exist and errors out to say that the user does not exist.

```
  region                  = "${var.aws_region}"
  shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
  profile                 = "aws-users-account
}

resource "aws_iam_user" "upload_iam_user" {
  name = "${var.service_name}"
}

resource "aws_iam_access_key" "upload_iam_access_key" {
  user = "${aws_iam_user.upload_iam_user.name}"
}

resource "aws_iam_user_login_profile" "upload_iam_password" {
  user    = "${aws_iam_user.upload_iam_user.name}"
  pgp_key = "${var.key}"
}

resource "aws_iam_user_group_membership" "upload_iam_group_add" {
  user = "${aws_iam_user.upload_iam_user.name}"
  groups = "${var.group_name}"
}
```

The above code works only for new users. what is the logic I can use to 
first : check if the input user exists, if it does, then add the group list that is given
second: check if the inpout user exists, if no, create it and add the groups

TIA

Comment: Like any resource, if you want TF to manage anything it didn't create, you'll have to import it into terraform. Once it is imported, terraform will manage it like any other resource (converging toward the desired state defined in your templates).

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html and https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_user.html#import should help.

Comment: Hello @Adrian Thank you for your reply. I have tried import as well. But did not solve the purpose. I can import only one user at a time. would it be possible to import all the users and then check? If I can import only one user at a time, how do you suggest  that I write the code?

I prev, tried it as

    data structure to check for the user, if it exists, import it and then add the group. If not, create it. It breaks, I can only check if user exists and the code ends with the message, can it continuously work? without exiting?

Comment: Terraform doesn't work that way. It applies a desired state to infrastructure. What you're describing is very programmatic, which just doesn't fit the Terraform model. They call it "infrastructure as code" but really it's "infrastructure as configuration". You can import all users, just one at a time. But `terraform import x` is just a shell command, so if you wanted to script against it, you certainly could. AWS CLI will let you list users.

Comment: yep that makes sense, I am pretty new to terraform, I was able to write a ruby&python code for it earlier and do a list all and check if a user exists and do etc.

From your exp, could you pls suggest how to go about it? write a code using ruby and list all users. but how would terraform call and use this?

Comment: Terraform wouldn't call it or use it. Please re-read my comments. You could write a script to list users in AWS and `terraform import` each user.

Comment: Thank you @Adrian hmm, I am not sure if I am not being clear. im sorry. But terraform does not seem to have enough detailed docs. 
yep, I got that wrt the script but what I meant to ask is the whole scenario of how terraform takes it, I did an import of all users, but the users keys are not stored as the API cannot call keys.

When I look up for user using data, it says user exits but it still creates a new pair of keys which should not, wrt my constraints as I mentioned in my question. 

using your experience, do you think all of this can be solved using terraform? I dont  think so.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... if you provide a different key in TF than what exists in AWS, then yes, it will update it; that's TF's whole purpose. If you don't want it to change it you'll need to have TF use the existing keys. If you don't have access to them, that will not be possible.

Comment: Thank you for your response @adrian seems like we both are on different pages. I have all the access to the keys. The keys that were previously manually created cannot be imported, it updates with a new key if a user is already created.

I tried and tested all ways, and terraform makes it complex for a simple script, probably not something terraform is built for.

Thank you for your help and time.